# How can I count the number of rows that match a query, but only return a subset in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

At present, I have this code:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE MATCH (`name`, `blurb`) AGAINST (:quer IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT $rpage, $max_show;");
$result->execute(array(":quer" => $query));

$count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE MATCH (`name`, `blurb`) AGAINST (:quer IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
$count->execute(array(":quer" => $query));
```

The first query grabs a bunch of rows from the table. The second one counts the rows that match the same criteria as the first, allowing for pagination.

Can I combine these two queries into one? And would it be more efficient?

Comment: What is the database? Is it the mySQL?

Comment: @Michas: Yes, it's a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

check into using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. You add that to your select in the first query and then just call SELECT FOUND_ROWS() after. You can read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows. and yes this would be more efficient than running the search query 2 times.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is a solution, but (not the fastest solution)[http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/].

Comment: interesting read but it is 4 years old and on mysql's website itself it says    `If you are using SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, MySQL must calculate how many rows are in the full result set. However, this is faster than running the query again without LIMIT, because the result set need not be sent to the client.`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [benchmarks of the MySQL experts at mysqlperformanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/), **running two seperate queries will probably be faster** than combining both in one query.